# SQL Server Agent Job, Access Denied

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, sql-server-agent

I have a T-SQL agent job that I've created that adds steps to itself depending on a query of the MSDB database.

I am able to run the query outside of the agent, inside a query editor window, but when I try to run the query as a job I get the following errors:

> Executed as user: [user with sysadmin rights for testing]. The SELECT
>   permission was denied on the object 'sysjobsteps' database 'msdb',
>   schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (error 229) The EXECUTE permission was
>   denied on the object 'sp_update_jobstep', database 'msdb', schema
>   'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229). The step failed

As I said in the error, I've tried this with a user with LUA, a user with the sysadmin role over the server, a user with owner role on the msdb database, and I've tried explicitly granting the needed permissions on the msdb database.

What have I done wrong in the creation of the agent job?

Let me know if you need more info.

UPDATE: I removed the `Run As:` user from the Advanced tab of the step and the job ran successfully.  Why doesn't that work as I expected it to?

Comment: `that adds steps to itself` - can you explain why? Something doesn't smell right.

Comment: Can you clearify what you mean here "I have a T-SQL agent job that I've created that adds steps to itself depending on a query of the MSDB database." ?????

Comment: I have a job that has a separate step to back up each database.  The first step in the job determines if any databases have been added or removed and adds or removes a step from the job to accommodate it.  It was a bit hacked because the maintenance plan wizard was having similar issues.  I've since abandoned this tactic and engineered something similar with powershell, which works much better in this environment.